# unable to install Vistual Studio 2017 for Mac

Tags: xamarin, visual-studio-2017, macos-high-sierra

I am tried to install Visual Studio 2017 on MAC . 
Error occurred during installation (Mac iOS have High Sierra , Version 10.13.2)..  Any help will be appreciated .
The Mac PC is new with Xcode Version 9.2 installed.

[ScreenShot For error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IYPmi.png)

---

```
Error downloading from Mono server. Mono Framework.
Message: The operation has timed out.
Exception type: System.Net.WebException

at System.Net.WebConnectionStream.Read (System.Byte[] buffer, System.Int32 offset, System.Int32 size) [0x00055] in /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.Mac.framework/Versions/2.10.0.113/src/mono/mcs/class/System/System.Net/WebConnectionStream.cs:338
at Xamarin.Web.Installer.DownloadService.DoDownload (System.Int64 totalBytes, System.IO.Stream responseStream, System.IO.Stream outputStream, System.Object state) [0x00087] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/5758/ce9029ec/source/installer/Xamarin.Web.Installer/DownloadService.cs:285
at Xamarin.Web.Installer.Utilities.DownloadUrl (System.Net.WebResponse response, System.String url, System.Action`4[T1,T2,T3,T4] doDownload, System.Action`1[T] reportProgress, System.Boolean noCache, System.Object state, System.IO.Stream outputStream, System.String targetFileName) [0x000c7] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/5758/ce9029ec/source/installer/Xamarin.Web.Installer/Utilities.cs:1071

Mono Framework installation failed with more than one exception (Attempt #3)
Message: Some installation errors are present.
Exception type: System.AggregateException

at Xamarin.Web.Installer.Installer.BaseSoftwareItem.ValidateDownloadItem () [0x0008f] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/5758/ce9029ec/source/installer/Xamarin.Web.Installer/Installer/BaseSoftwareItem.cs:501
at Xamarin.Web.Installer.Installer.BaseSoftwareItem.Install (System.UInt32 tryNumber) [0x0003e] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/5758/ce9029ec/source/installer/Xamarin.Web.Installer/Installer/BaseSoftwareItem.cs:289
at MacInstaller.WizardPageInstallationController.InstallationWorker () [0x00145] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/5758/ce9029ec/source/installer/MacInstaller.Universal/WizardPageInstallationController.cs:541
at System.Net.WebConnectionStream.Read (System.Byte[] buffer, System.Int32 offset, System.Int32 size) [0x00055] in /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.Mac.framework/Versions/2.10.0.113/src/mono/mcs/class/System/System.Net/WebConnectionStream.cs:338
at Xamarin.Web.Installer.DownloadService.DoDownload (System.Int64 totalBytes, System.IO.Stream responseStream, System.IO.Stream outputStream, System.Object state) [0x00087] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/5758/ce9029ec/source/installer/Xamarin.Web.Installer/DownloadService.cs:285
at Xamarin.Web.Installer.Utilities.DownloadUrl (System.Net.WebResponse response, System.String url, System.Action`4[T1,T2,T3,T4] doDownload, System.Action`1[T] reportProgress, System.Boolean noCache, System.Object state, System.IO.Stream outputStream, System.String targetFileName) [0x000c7] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/5758/ce9029ec/source/installer/Xamarin.Web.Installer/Utilities.cs:1071
at Xamarin.Web.Installer.Installer.BaseSoftwareItem.ValidateDownloadItem () [0x0008f] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/5758/ce9029ec/source/installer/Xamarin.Web.Installer/Installer/BaseSoftwareItem.cs:501
at Xamarin.Web.Installer.Installer.BaseSoftwareItem.Install (System.UInt32 tryNumber) [0x0003e] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/5758/ce9029ec/source/installer/Xamarin.Web.Installer/Installer/BaseSoftwareItem.cs:289
at MacInstaller.WizardPageInstallationController.InstallationWorker () [0x00145] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/5758/ce9029ec/source/installer/MacInstaller.Universal/WizardPageInstallationController.cs:541
at System.Net.WebConnectionStream.Read (System.Byte[] buffer, System.Int32 offset, System.Int32 size) [0x00055] in /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.Mac.framework/Versions/2.10.0.113/src/mono/mcs/class/System/System.Net/WebConnectionStream.cs:338
at Xamarin.Web.Installer.DownloadService.DoDownload (System.Int64 totalBytes, System.IO.Stream responseStream, System.IO.Stream outputStream, System.Object state) [0x00087] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/5758/ce9029ec/source/installer/Xamarin.Web.Installer/DownloadService.cs:285
at Xamarin.Web.Installer.Utilities.DownloadUrl (System.Net.WebResponse response, System.String url, System.Action`4[T1,T2,T3,T4] doDownload, System.Action`1[T] reportProgress, System.Boolean noCache, System.Object state, System.IO.Stream outputStream, System.String targetFileName) [0x000c7] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/5758/ce9029ec/source/installer/Xamarin.Web.Installer/Utilities.cs:1071
at Xamarin.Web.Installer.Installer.BaseSoftwareItem.ValidateDownloadItem () [0x0008f] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/5758/ce9029ec/source/installer/Xamarin.Web.Installer/Installer/BaseSoftwareItem.cs:501
at Xamarin.Web.Installer.Installer.BaseSoftwareItem.Install (System.UInt32 tryNumber) [0x0003e] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/5758/ce9029ec/source/installer/Xamarin.Web.Installer/Installer/BaseSoftwareItem.cs:289
at MacInstaller.WizardPageInstallationController.InstallationWorker () [0x00145] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/5758/ce9029ec/source/installer/MacInstaller.Universal/WizardPageInstallationController.cs:541
at System.Net.WebConnectionStream.Read (System.Byte[] buffer, System.Int32 offset, System.Int32 size) [0x00055] in /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.Mac.framework/Versions/2.10.0.113/src/mono/mcs/class/System/System.Net/WebConnectionStream.cs:338
at Xamarin.Web.Installer.DownloadService.DoDownload (System.Int64 totalBytes, System.IO.Stream responseStream, System.IO.Stream outputStream, System.Object state) [0x00087] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/5758/ce9029ec/source/installer/Xamarin.Web.Installer/DownloadService.cs:285
at Xamarin.Web.Installer.Utilities.DownloadUrl (System.Net.WebResponse response, System.String url, System.Action`4[T1,T2,T3,T4] doDownload, System.Action`1[T] reportProgress, System.Boolean noCache, System.Object state, System.IO.Stream outputStream, System.String targetFileName) [0x000c7] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/5758/ce9029ec/source/installer/Xamarin.Web.Installer/Utilities.cs:1071
```

Comment: "The operation has timed out" - either you're having connectivity issues, or their server is.  Try again later

Comment: Internet is up , internet is working fine. no issues.

Comment: finally, the VS is installed . I only connect to another WiFi internet. :)